# My program returns the wrong values

Tags: c, linux

I am making a program that will calculate the minimum and maximum cost of flight (supposed to be a simple program to practice for an exam) using a separate function to calculate the cost of the flight.
the code is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
float cost(float k, int ck, int n)
{
    int x;
    x = (k*ck)/n;
    return x;
}
main()
{
    int cont=1, n, nv, costmax = 0, costmin = INT_MAX, ck;
    float k;
    printf("Introduce the number of flights: \n");
    scanf("%d", &nv);
    for(cont=1; cont <= nv; cont++)
    {
        printf("Introduce the number of passangers on flight %d:\n", cont);
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Introduce the number of distance on flight %d:\n", cont);
        scanf("%d", &k);
        if(k < 500)
        {
            ck=50;
        }
        if(k > 500)
        {
            ck=80;
        }
        cost(k,ck,n);
        if(cost(k, ck, n) < costmin)
        {
            costmin = cost(k, ck, n);
        }
        if(cost(k, ck, n) > costmax)
        {
            costmax = cost(k, ck, n);
        }
    }
    printf("\nMinimum cost = %d \n", costmin);
    printf("\nMaximum cost = %d \n", costmax);
}
```

and we're supposed to use a text file to input the data

```
156 397 798 375 489 901 937 519 797 205 883 247 1186 738 860 967 550 887 743 753 906 582 819 665 1112 231 1009 761 921 634 686 591 1027 646 1161 424 668 413 1190 423 840 381 431 559 455 496 1105 489 848 775 456 637 664 760 412 689 639 752 669 312 940 955 706 726 579 556 655 335 902 755 665 431 1093 627 569 310 647 327 943 354 647 733 979 711 504 443 509 266 833 856 667 603 1101 670 688 898 498 669 1149 601 808 934 718 880 1053 977 556 719 1012 286 665 882 456 623 437 632 475 320 494 672 775 548 678 935 984 464 1188 641 749 816 1191 528 1092 203 770 923 1153 220 929 321 789 350 720 745 694 790 687 669 826 372 1029 392 839 932 462 806 882 539 524 797 1084 516 449 218 1048 638 751 889 448 479 465 633 1123 862 904 383 494 472 1117 365 415 889 765 670 941 341 929 876 575 940 565 967 850 473 1119 632 953 904 815 316 409 364 959 287 848 584 574 998 915 826 558 877 858 376 817 591 1068 443 447 428 1081 823 1122 373 852 598 995 735 1028 313 623 820 981 505 753 529 574 433 699 875 1032 833 1068 765 949 691 1145 358 505 251 617 417 945 694 889 323 1028 986 567 269 605 337 1153 926 590 607 803 202 1101 232 771 855 759 776 1011 878 884 393 636 230 1098 788 1140 447 1076 537 1077 734 724 266 635 232 406 752 628 743 848 537 490 598 913 416 855 640 634 209 1172 329 705 249 881 882 817
```

The program doesn't present any errors or warnings when compiling, but when I run it, it says that the minimum cost and the maximum cost are 0...
I've been checking everything over and over and can't find what's wrong.
Any ideas?

BTW, I'm using a linux machine to run the program, don't know if it makes a difference...

Comment: `cost()` returns float, but x is int. As the other answers mention, it will pay to check the types you are passing around.  integer division truncates to  zero and this will cause issues

Comment: I recommend more descriptive parameter and variable names... And then use an editor or an IDE, which will do autocompletion/intellisense for you, to reduce the temptation to use one-letter variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `k` is a `float`, this is wrong:

```
scanf("%d", &k);
```

You need:

```
if (scanf("%f", &k) != 1)
    break;
```

This uses the correct format and checks for errors.  A basic debugging technique is to print out the values you've just read to ensure that the program got what you think it should have gotten.

---

There are other problems too. This code is redundant:

```
    cost(k,ck,n);
    if(cost(k, ck, n) < costmin)
    {
        costmin = cost(k, ck, n);
    }
    if(cost(k, ck, n) > costmax)
    {
        costmax = cost(k, ck, n);
    }
```

You call the function up to 5 times to get the same answer each time. The first call you ignore altogether.  You should probably use something like:

```
    float new_cost = cost(k,ck,n);
    if (new_cost < costmin)
        costmin = new_cost;
    if (new_cost > costmax)
        costmax = cost_max;
```

You should also use an explicit return type for `main()`:

```
int main(void)
```

Normally, 'passengers' is spelled with one 'a' and two 'e's.

It isn't entirely clear whether the `cost()` function is written appropriately. It takes one `float` and two `int` values and combines them and assigns the result to an `int` before returning that as a `float`.  As written, it will work. Whether that's what you want is another matter. Since `costmin` and `costmax` are of type `int`, there's another level of uncertainty about what's the best type for these values.

Also, generally avoid trailing blanks in your output.  A space before `\n` is almost always … well, if not wrong, superfluous.  I'd go for almost always wrong, though.  (But it is good that you end messages with a newline — that's a worse problem than trailing blanks, but prevalent in the world of C on Windows.)

Comment: +1. I'd give another +1 for the prototype for `main`

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, didn't even notice i was using %d, which makes me feel quite stupid. i changed it o %f and it worked, didn't even need to break.

Answer (score 3):

Compile with the `-Wall` flag, this will help you to catch errors by yourself.

**Using gcc:**

```
 % gcc t.c -Wall
t.c:9:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
 main()
 ^
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:20:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d", &k);
         ^
t.c:41:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

**Using clang:**

```
 % clang t.c -Wall
t.c:9:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^~~~
t.c:20:21: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'float *' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%d", &k);
               ~~   ^~
               %f
2 warnings generated.
```

Clang suggests you to replace:

```
scanf("%d", &k);
```

to

```
scanf("%f", &k);
```

And even if it's not as critical, you forgot to define the return type of the main function. Both compilers have replaced it to `int` but you should also `return` something at the end of your program.

Finally, as suggested in the comments, you can also use `-Wextra`. I would also recommend you, while the projects are small enough and that you are still learning, to respect the "0 warning" policy. That will help you to prevent bugs.

Comment: hum... dont really know any of these commands yet, but i already solved it, thank you very much

Comment: Also, `-Wextra` (gcc, same in clang?) would not hurt either, especially when OP is learning and should avoid any "dangerous" things as much as C allows...

Comment: +1: "If you give a man a fish, you feed him for a day. If you teach a man how to fish, you feed him for life."

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I see no reading from file. All your readings are from console (stdin).
Also, you are calling the cost function too many times, and sometimes you take no benefit from it, like here:

```
    }
    cost(k,ck,n); //<--
    if(cost(k, ck, n) < costmin)
```

I suggest you replace indicated call with:

float c = cost(k, ck, n);

and then use c for checking/assingments instead of calling cost() all over again.

Also, you are assigning a float value to an int in multiple places:

```
costmax = cost(k, ck, n);
costmin = cost(k, ck, n);
```

In some places, you use "%d" in scanf and printf for reading/printing a float. You should use "%f".

Comment: Programs get run: `./test_program < datafile` so 'reading from file' and 'reading from standard input' are essentially the same unless the program is given a command line argument that is the file to be read.